# Spring - Xsd file with constructor

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

I have an entity class auto-generated from xsd file;
the problem is that it hasn't any constructor and I must add it manual.

How can I specify a constructor? 
Here my xsd file:

**entities.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:tns="http://capgemini.it/soap/entity/generated"
       targetNamespace="http://capgemini.it/soap/entity/generated" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="getEntityRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getEntityResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="entity" type="tns:entity"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="entity">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="cf" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="role" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="valid" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element name="isIta" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element name="sesso" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element name="nationalNumber" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="crs" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lvlId" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="qual" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Thanks for any suggestion :)

Comment: You cannot as that is not what an xsd is for. Also why would you need to add a constructor? A default no-arg constructor is by default available.

Comment: Because I want to use the entity generated from xsd file, isn't this the right approach?

Comment: Then just use it. As stated a constructor is ALWAYS available even if not explicitly defined (then there is a default no-args constructor). So again why would you need to add a constructor to be able to use the generated class. You can simply do `new Entity()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what if I want a constructor with params?

Comment: You will have to add it yourself, but generally that isn't a wise thing to do. Those generated classes are also used by marshalling/unmarshalling frameworks and that except a no-args constructor. Also you shouldn't (IMHO) be using those things as entities in your application, only for transport (as a contract). It is an integration point for your application.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much.
How can I correctly "close" the question?